# firebase Uncaught TypeError: db.ref is not a function error

Tags: javascript, firebase

I keep getting the following error when I am trying to set a variable in firebase but I keep getting the following error `Uncaught TypeError: db.ref is not a function` not sure what im doing wrong because I have already initialized `db` I have tried importing `ref` hoping that might fix it but still no dice.

```js
      // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
      import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.14.0/firebase-app.js";
      import { getDatabase, ref, set, get } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.14.0/firebase-database.js";

      // Your web app's Firebase configuration
      const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyAalz5fFuOOG6_EZVFIO-hJRA2Sw1Yyg2A",
        authDomain: "lost-and-found-system-67568.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://lost-and-found-system-67568-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "lost-and-found-system-67568",
        storageBucket: "lost-and-found-system-67568.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "32608786023",
        appId: "1:32608786023:web:6aea01187ecb53ce6a66c2"
      };

        // Initialize Firebase
        const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        const db = getDatabase(app);
        coleccionProductos = db.ref().child("productos");
        bodyProductos = $("#bodyProductos").val();
        //console.log(bodyProductos);
```

Answer (score 0):

In firestore V9, the methods and syntaxes are a bit different.

Instead of **db.ref()** you should use **ref**:

```js
const db = getDatabase(app);
const dbref = ref(db);
```

And instead of **.child** you should use **child**:

```js
const coleccionProductos = child(dbref, "productos");
```

**And as an important note, don't share your keys and ids.**